# Show that $PSL(2,2)$ and $PSL(2,3)$ are not simple groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

**Show that** $PSL(2,2)$ and $PSL(2,3)$ are **not** simple groups.

**My intuition:**

**Is it enough to say that** these two groups are solvable since $PSL(2,2)$ has order $6$ and is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$, and $PSL(2,3)$ has order $12$ and is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_4$. And thus, aren't simple?

Comment: There are no simple non-abelian groups of order $6$ and $12$, so you are done. You can use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272439/derived-subgroups-of-sl2-2-sl2-3-and-gl2-3?rq=1) for solvability.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Right, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know that $\text{PSL}(2,2)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, then you can just specify one non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $S_3$, namely the subgroup $A_3$ generated by a $3$-cycle (by the isomorphism this group will get mapped to a non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $\text{PSL}(2,2)$ then.

Analogously for $A_4$, by considering the Klein-$4$-group $V_4 \subset A_4$.

Comment: Thank you. will accept the answer when the cooldown of accepting an answer is done

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: How to show that $PSL(2,3) \cong A_4$?